# Where can I download "Code128a" barcode font?

Tags: reporting-services, barcode, barcode-printing, code128

I take a google but it is not found Barcode font which it is Code128 type "A" format.

My report need to show barcode which it was generate by string like these

```
    00-KGH-15132-9000-Y3#"
    0006000149000(00) 
    ZP50000070#
```

I has only code128 type "B" but it's not support some charactor.
I need type "A" because it support ASCII.

Please to tell me, Where can I download  "Code128" type A barcode font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is no different between Code 128A and Code 128B. The same sequences of thick and thin lines are used. It is the conversion from ASCII and numeric characters to barcode sequence that differs. The same font should be usable for either application, but your application needs to send the "Start Code A (103)" character to print instead of the "Start Code B (104)".

The software you use will need to adjust for the differences between extended ASCII code 64 and up. For example, you will need to send a lower case 'm' to generate a  (carriage return) and a lowercase 'j' to get a  (line feed).